# how i can fix player variable is not define error?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

When I call my player function it shows an error:
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'player' is not defined.

```py
def main():
    player='x'

    def switchplayer():
        global player

        if player == 'x':  # use double equal because its boolean       
              player = 'O'
        else:
              player = 'x'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Is `switchplayer` inside `main`?

Comment: You need `nonlocal player`, not `global player`.

Comment: Instead of using `global`/`nonlocal`, which are generally considered code smells, you should consider a `class` to hold the game state.

Comment: ponit is i shouldt use a class

Comment: @Barmar nonlocal worked thank you!